# How can I extract the contour data from mayavi.mlab.contour3d object?

Tags: python, mayavi.mlab

I am plotting the 3d contours of some 3d scalar field using mayavi.mlab.contour3d.
It works very well but I would like to extract the data associated with these contours so I can compute the volume contained in the 3d contours / isosurfaces.
Does anyone know if it possible to access this information and how ?

For now I have tried to look in the different attributes of the object generated by :

`import mayavi.mlab as mlab`
`obj = mlab.contour3d(scalar_field)`

where scalar_field is any 3D scalar field.

But `obj` is constituted of many objects as well so this method seems laborious.

I might just iterate through one axis of my 3D data and compute 2d contours instead but this might also be inefficient.